# Не удалось найти пакет mongodb-org

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

устанавливаю по руководству с офф. сайта [Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

1. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927`
2. для **Ubuntu 14.04** : `echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse"`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

и здесь возникает проблема:

> E: Не удалось найти пакет mongodb-org

Как установить нормально MongoDB, или как сделать так, чтобы удалось все найти?

Comment: Аналогичная ситуация, `update` сообщает в конце: `W: Не удалось получить http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/wily/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found` и `E: Некоторые индексные файлы не скачались. Они были проигнорированы или вместо них были использованы старые версии.`

Comment: Автор, сколько битная у вас система?

Comment: @Mi Ke Bu Ubuntu 14.04  64-bit

Comment: Моя проблема заключалась в невнимательности и 32-битности. Переставил на Lubuntu 15.10 64-bit - проблема исчезла. А у вас `apt-get update` не выдает предупреждения (W:) и ошибки (E:)?

Comment: @Mi Ke Bu нет, при `apt-get update` все норм, ошибка вылетает при `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` но ответ который мне дал alexander barakin полностью помог. теперь все ок, установилось без проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на втором шаге вы не полностью скопировали команду:

```
$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

после неё повторите шаги 3 и 4.